# MongoDB Performance With $nin query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of 1000000 documents. I want to fetch those documents whose uid not in the given uids.so I am using mongo find query along with $nin so the query looks like:

> {uid:{$nin:[1,2,3......500000}}

but suppose in future my documents count increase and I am passing more uid with $nin query.

Doses Mongo with $nin query affects query performance? Is any other option to achieve this without using $nin query?

Comment: You're question is unclear as obviously when scale goes up performance goes down in regards to any query. `$nin` specifically is bad at utilizing indexes as it still needs to scan large portions of data. if this series is monotone and dense try using `$gt` instead?

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I can't able to use $gt in my case my uid is a mix of number and string.but is any other option like $nin so I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

A query that retrieves half of the documents in the collection is very likely going to be executed with a collection scan. At this point the conditions don't matter too much.

With that said, an index generally won't be used to answer negative queries ("where X is not Y") so you should consider rewording your conditions to be positive rather than negative.